# Is it possible to lease a car in Canada as a non-resident?

Tags: canada, car, non-resident, auto-leasing

I'm a non resident of Canada, living in Vancouver, BC, Canada - what are the rules, regs and issues in leasing a car - is it even possible?

Comment: Have you asked a car dealership? Essentially a lease is just a fixed term loan, so it's probably up to the financier.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean that you've been deemed a non-resident for tax purposes but that you've returned to Canada?  Do you intend to re-establish residency?

As a non-resident, it may be difficult to obtain credit from any Canadian financial institution, and similarly leasing a vehicle may be difficult as well.

Have you investigated longer-term rental options?

Comment: Longer term rental options are MUCH more expensive than a lease.